# AngularJS select element value is an object, why?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object like:

```
{
    "9000A": {
        "LOCname":"A Location"
        "LOCid":"9000A"
    },
    "2700C": {
        "LOCname":"C Location"
        "LOCid":"2700C"
    },
    "7600B": {
        "LOCname":"B Location"
        "LOCid":"7600B"
    }
}
```

I need to sort it by LOCname to display in a select list, I do this using a custom filter that turns the JSON object into an array:

```
<select name="location" ng-model="formData.location" ng-options="loc.LOCname for loc in (locations | json2array | orderBy:'LOCname') track by loc.LOCid">
    <option style="display:none" value="" disabled selected>Choose a location.</option>
</select>
```

This works great my options look like:

```
<option value="9000A" label="A Location">A Location</option>
<option value="7600B" label="B Location">B Location</option>
<option value="2700C" label="C Location">C Location</option>
```

My problem is that formData.location is now equal to an object:

```
{"LOCname":"A Location","LOCid":"9000A"}
```

Expected result is that formData.location would be equal to "9000A"

Anyone able to explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: you have to use formData.location.LOCid now to get 9000A.

Comment: But why is an object being assigned to a form field? I am selecting an option with a value of "9000A" I don't understand how the object is being assigned to formData.location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of the way u use `ng-options`

if you use ng-options as

```
ng-options="color.LOCid as loc.LOCname for loc in (locations |..."
```

you can select the `ID`

explanation

> color.LOCid as loc.LOCname for loc in (locations |...
>
> location is the array we need to iterate
>
> loc is a single object
>   loc.LOCname for 'loc.LOCname' is the value we need to show
>
> color.LOCid in is the value of selected option
>
> (if you do not set "color.LOCid in") by default is select the whole object in your case its `loc`

Comment: greate, :) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select please have a look at the doc here. there is more details about `ng-options` chreez :)

Comment: @Craig Keep in mind that using this form of ng-options results in your <select>'s <option> elements losing values of their "value" attributes. They will be replaced with placeholder values 0, 1, 2..N.

Comment: @Craig Also, don't forget to remove "track by loc.LOCid" from your ng-options expression as it's not supposed to be used with this alternative form of ng-options.

Comment: @m1kael the very reason I am using track by is to keep the value attribute. Can you explain why I would not want to use track by? will it lead to problems?

Comment: @Craig Yes it will when you try to preserve selection. You track by loc.LOCid. But when track by is applied to an already selected value (the value of your ng-model) which is now a string, say "9000A", it won't be able to find .LOCid on that string and your <select> will always be reset to the "not selected" option. Here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select it is explicitly said: "Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together."